# Find items using Laravel ORM

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

I am having two tables in my database presented as follow.

`offers(table)`

```
id
name
```

`features(table)`

```
id
offer_id
name
```

What I am trying to do is to retrieve the various `offers`, for a given set of `features`.
So I try using the following code but I am not getting the results expected:

```
$offers = Feature::find(['1', '2', '3'])->offers;
```

For instance:`features` with the id of `1` and `2` belongs to `offer 1`.

`feature 3` belongs to `offer 3`.

From the code above, I am want `$offers` to contain only two elements `offer 1 and 2`

I try using the code below but the `offers` are duplicated:

```
$offers = DB::table('features')
           ->whereIn('features.id', ['1', '2', '3'])
           ->join('offers', 'offers.id', '=', 'features.offer_id')
           ->get();
```

kindly help me solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$offers = DB::table('features')
->whereIn('features.id', ['1', '2', '3'])
->join('offers', 'offers.id', '=', 'features.offer_id')
->groupBy('offers.id')
->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try this `features.offer_id` instead of `id` in where in condition

```
$offers = DB::table('features')
           ->whereIn('features.offer_id', ['1', '2', '3'])
           ->join('offers', 'offers.id', '=', 'features.offer_id')
           ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem by using the following code. Hope it can be improved:

```
    $offers = [];

    $features = Feature::find(['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']);

    foreach($features as $feature) {
        $offers[$feature->offer_id] = $feature->offer;
    }

    dd($offers);
```